# Create a boolean that resets it's value at midnight?

Tags: java, android, boolean

Is there a simple way to create a boolean that resets its value to false at midnight?

I thought in using an if statment like

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar midnight = Calendar.getInstance();
    midnight.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    midnight.add(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
    midnight.add(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

    if (now == midnight){
        boolean = false;
    }
```

But it only works if the activity is running and I need it to run even if the app is closed

I know I can do it using the **AlarmManager** and the **Shared Preferences** but I was wondering if there is a more obvious an easy way that I've not thought off.

Comment: why do you need that

Comment: Use intentService or job scheduler for this kind of task

Comment: I want to keep track if the user didn't click a button. This button onClick changes the boolean to true. And at the end of the day if the boolean is false (Button wasn't clicked) I'll add one increment to the missed clicks progress bar. And if it returns true I'll add one increment to the clicks progress bar. This is why I need the boolean to turn itself back to false at midnight so the next day the code repeats itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a kind of "Midnight Resetting Boolean" class for this. Get the value every time the Activity is loaded and increment the counter by one if it's false.

```
package com.bemoty.booleantest;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class MidnightBoolean {

    private boolean value = true;
    private long lastChanged = 0L;

    public MidnightBoolean(boolean startValue) {
        this.setValue(startValue);
    }

    public void setValue(boolean value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.lastChanged = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public boolean getValue() {
        Calendar lastChangedCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar timeNowCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        lastChangedCalendar.setTime(new Date(lastChanged));
        if ((lastChangedCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) - timeNowCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) < 0) {
            this.setValue(false);
        }
        return this.value;
    }
}
```